# innerHTML with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am creating a Memory game and i want to add animation when you flip a card.
My code is based on this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_ohDPWmsM0

Here i am displaying the picture but i would like to add a flip animation when you click on a card.

```
  if(tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2){

     tile.innerHTML = '<img class="img-tile" src="assets/' + val + '.png"/>';
  }
```

I tried to do so with jQuery but it's not working.

```
 tile.fadeOut(1000, function(){
      tile.html('<img class="img-tile" src="assets/' + val + '.png"/>').fadeIn(1000);
 });
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not very specific. Please create a minimal example (e.g. in a JSFiddle or code snippet). We need to see the original HTML of the page too :)

Comment: You might want to look at the http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp transform around the y axis. with two absolutely positioned divs in a relative div and shifting the z index when they are at 90 degree angle.

Comment: TrueBlueAussie, here is the code :

http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Memory-Game-Programming-Tutorial

Comment: I meant a minimal example of *your* code (not the original Javascript sample you are converting) :)

Comment: @MichaelDibbets you should avoid to link to `w3schools` they still suffer from inaccuracies. It is valid to leave the `-moz-` prefix out in the example and that the `-webkit-` is still required, but they do not mention why. It for sure is in this case a minor problem, but there are many question of beginners here on SO referencing a w3school page they learn from, asking why something is not working. And if you look then on that w3schools page you will most of the time see that it was a misunderstanding because of an inaccuracy.